# Click on a icon has to run another runnable jar

Tags: java, jar

I have created a runnable jar of my application. I want to change the default icon of that jar. Searched for almost two days and most of the sites said it depends on OS, can't be changed. So I think to do like this, by clicking on a different icon, my runnable has to run. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: And which OS *are* you interested in?

Comment: I need to run that jar in both windows an mac.

Comment: Then it sounds like you'll need to build a native binary on each of Winows and Mac which launches the jar file.

Comment: @Jon  If that is what it sounds like, you need to get your hearing checked.  JWS offers the ability to set an icon for the desktop shortcut that launches an app.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: That's why I suggested that the OP looked at Java Web Start in another comment. Or at least, I thought I did... it doesn't seem to have made it here. Very weird.

Comment: @Jon If you need a hearing check, I need a memory tonic, since it seems I *had* previously recommended JWS to this same OP.  :(

Comment: And on that matter, you might take more effort in writing your question.  For 2 examples 1) Specify the details of the OS support required. and 2) Explain how commonly suggested solutions will not serve your use-case.  **You might also consider answering questions in comments, rather than ignore them as you did in your last question.**  After all, SO is not a help-desk.

Comment: Thanks Andrew and Jon for your comments. Previously,for this project I created exe for windows and app for Mac. But my client want as a single executable which runs on both OS. Thats why I go for runnable jar. And moreover it is for distribution to many and not for single one.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to change the default icon..

Launch the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  As part of the desktop integration it offers the ability to set an icon for the desktop shortcut (or menu item).

> I need to run that jar in both windows an mac.

JWS works in 'both' Windows, *nix & Mac.

Comment: I need to distribute that jar along with that icon to my clients.

Comment: What does that mean in your head?  Does it mean "..so I cannot use JWS"?  If so, note that I am not telepathic, so **be specific.**